# Java-based 2 way chat application not working

Tags: java, network-programming

> For  its partner app I switched the Client and Server code and the ports. Ran both these codes in two separate terminals. They were able to connect with each other but I was not able send message from one terminal to the other.

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
class ChatHead1
{  
 public static void main()throws Exception
 {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

   //Client   
   Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2000);  
   OutputStream ostream = sock.getOutputStream();  
   DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(ostream);  
   System.out.print("\nYou:");   
   String message1 = br.readLine();  //Inputting Message For Sending
   dos.writeBytes(message1);

   //Server
   ServerSocket sersock = new ServerSocket(5000);
   System.out.print("\nThem: ");
   Socket sockServ = sersock.accept();
   InputStream istream = sockServ.getInputStream();
   DataInputStream dstream = new DataInputStream(istream);
   String message2 = dstream.readLine();
   System.out.println(message2);    //Printing Received Message

   //Client Close
   dos.close();
   ostream.close();
   sock.close();

   //Server Close
   dstream .close();
   istream.close();
   sockServ.close();
   sersock.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: "Terminal?"  Could you be more specific, a "terminal" to me means  VT100, but I doubt you're running Java on one.  What exactly is your hardware and network configuration, and what errors are you getting when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: @markspace, by terminal I meant Command Prompt. Sorry for the improper word. Got it working though by closing Output stream before starting Input stream.. Thanks for a such quick response.. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you should only use one Server/Client, because its a two way connection.
I dont really see why you are using a Client **and** a Server.

Try `dos.flush();` after `dos.writeBytes(message1);`

Comment: Client and Server is only the terminology I have used to signify the code which sends and receive the message. If I use *Client* code and don't use InputStream, how can I receive messages?

Comment: Nevermind, got it working.. Figured out that I needed to close the Client's Stream before starting Server's.. Thanks for reminding about the flush though.. :D

Comment: He means: it looks like all this code is in 1 program.